# D-flop with enable and clear, translated from VHDL to Haskell

Tags: haskell, comparative-review, vhdl

I am in the process of translating an implementation of [dflop_en_clr](http://www.readler.com/codesamples_VHDL.pdf) from VHDL to Haskell:

> ```
> if (reset = '1') then
>      out_1 <= '0';
> elsif rising_edge(clk) then
>    if (clear_n = '0') then
>       out_1 <= '0';
>    elsif (enable = '1') then
>       out_1 <= in_1;
>    end if; 
> end if;
> ```

**Types to know:**

```
data PIn = PIn { _in_1    :: Bit
               , _clk     :: Bit
               , _reset   :: Bool
               , _enable  :: Bool
               , _clear_n :: Bool
               } deriving (Eq)

data St = St { _out_1 :: Bit
             } deriving (Eq)
```

**First attempt**

```
 onTrue :: St -> PIn -> Bool -> St
 onTrue st PIn{..} edgeDetect = shouldReset
   where
     shouldReset = if _reset then St 0 else risingEdge
     risingEdge  = if edgeDetect then shouldClear else st
     shouldClear = if _clear_n then St 0 else enabled
     enabled     = if _enable then st{ _out_1 = _in_1 }  else st
```

**Another**:

```
onTrue'' :: St -> PIn -> Bool -> St
onTrue'' st PIn{..} risingEdge = if _reset then St 0
                                 else if risingEdge  $
                                       if not _clear_n then St 0
                                       else if _enable then st{ _out_1 = _in_1 }
                                            else st
                                     else st
```

If I were to covert a more complicated nest logic then there would possible be a lot of extra "else"

**Current**:

```
ifTrueApplyFun :: Bool -> a -> (a -> a) -> a
ifTrueApplyFun cond value fun = if cond then fun value
                                else value
ifTrueReturnFun :: Bool -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
ifTrueReturnFun cond fun = if cond then fun
                           else id
onTrue' :: St -> PIn -> Bool -> St
onTrue' st PIn{..} risingEdge = if _reset then St 0
                                else ifTrueApplyFun risingEdge st $
                                       if not _clear_n then (\_ -> St 0)
                                       else ifTrueReturnFun _enable (\newSt -> newSt{ _out_1 = _in_1 })
```

This is code that needs to be readable and testable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think your first attempt is the most readable. The advantage over the VDHL implementation is that you're annotating each case with a function name. This makes it more self-documenting.

I would just multi-line your if-statements, like this:

```
onTrue :: St -> PIn -> Bool -> St
onTrue st PIn{..} edgeDetect = shouldReset
  where
    nullState = St 0
    shouldReset =
      if _reset
        then nullState
        else risingEdge
    risingEdge =
      if edgeDetect
        then shouldClear
        else st
    shouldClear =
      if _clear_n
        then nullState
        else enabled
    enabled =
      if _enable
        then st{ _out_1 = _in_1 }
        else st
```